# How to convert a cocoapod to typescript when there's no viewController exposed?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, typescript, cocoapods, nativescript

After doing a great "use an objc library in ns" tutorial on egghead.io by Nathan Walker, I wanted to test my new skills. I've started the same conversion process on [material-snackbar](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios/tree/develop/components/Snackbar).

This pod does not seem to expose the UIView or viewController itself (it's in a manager). How might you suggest I add it to the `appWindow.rootViewController`?

original code:

```
MDCSnackbarMessage *message = [[MDCSnackbarMessage alloc] init];
message.text = @"How much wood would a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood?";
[MDCSnackbarManager showMessage:message];
```

my typescript:

```
constuctor(){
    this._message = MDCSnackbarMessage.alloc().init(); 
}

public showMessage(m:string){
    this._message.text = m;
    MDCSnackbarManager.showMessage(this._message)
}
```

That works! **But nothing shows up in my app when I invoke it from my app controller.** So, my first guess would be to dig into the `MDCSnackBarManager` code to find a way to set the container. **I found it:**

```
(void)setPresentationHostView:(UIView *)hostView {
  NSAssert([NSThread isMainThread], @"setPresentationHostView must be called on main thread.");
  MDCSnackbarManagerInternal *manager = [MDCSnackbarManagerInternal sharedInstance];
  manager.presentationHostView = hostView;
}
```

so, I **tried this**:

```
MDCSnackbarManager.setPresentationHostView(rootVC());
const rootVC = function(){
    let appWindow = UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow;
    return appWindow.rootViewController;
}
```

it Crashes with the message below. How do I ensure the manager/messages are added to the root view properly?

```
*** JavaScript call stack:
    (
        0   UIApplicationMain@[native code]
        1   start@file:///app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/application/application.js:251:26
        2   bootstrapApp@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/platform-common.js:68:28
        3   bootstrapModule@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/platform-common.js:56:26
        4   anonymous@file:///app/main.js:4:57
        5   evaluate@[native code]
        6   moduleEvaluation@:1:11
        7   @:7:50
        8   promiseReactionJob@:1:11
    )
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationControllerImpl bounds]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff366920a00'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e7f9d4b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010e25b21e objc_exception_throw + 48
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e869f04 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
        3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e77f005 ___forwarding___ + 1013
        4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e80ca08 __forwarding_prep_1___ + 120
        5   MaterialComponents                  0x000000010aced0d4 -[MDCSnackbarManagerInternal activateOverlay:] + 612
        6   MaterialComponents                  0x000000010acebeeb -[MDCSnackbarManagerInternal displaySnackbarViewForMessage:] + 1163
        7   MaterialComponents                  0x000000010aceba40 -[MDCSnackbarManagerInternal showNextMessageIfNecessaryMainThread] + 496
        8   MaterialComponents                  0x000000010aced917 -[MDCSnackbarManagerInternal showMessageMainThread:] + 487
        9   MaterialComponents                  0x000000010aceec34 __34+[MDCSnackbarManager showMessage:]_block_invoke + 84
        10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010f4ff808 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
        11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010f52112e _dispatch_client_callout + 8
        12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010f5084fb _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1054
        13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e7bde49 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
        14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e78337d __CFRunLoopRun + 2205
        15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e782884 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
        16  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000111619a6f GSEventRunModal + 161
        17  UIKit                               0x000000010c015c68 UIApplicationMain + 159
        18  NativeScript                        0x000000010b48797d ffi_call_unix64 + 85
        19  ???                                 0x000000012a5fdf70 0x0 + 5005893488
    )
Mar 27 16:50:04 PODMB0079 SpringBoard[5820]: [KeyboardArbiter] HW kbd: Failed to set (null) as keyboard focus
Mar 27 16:50:04 PODMB0079 com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.CB2CCBE6-20D1-4283-908C-2232692E7AC0.launchd_sim[5804] (UIKitApplication:org.nativescript.podtest[0x8461][7291]): Service exited due to Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: I'm an idiot. i was passing the viewController instead of the view. so pass rootVC().view

Comment: This course might also help https://egghead.io/courses/use-objective-c-swift-and-java-api-s-in-nativescript-for-angular-ios-and-android-apps - lots of goodies for plain NS and Angular+NativeScript

Comment: And... I just realized you mention Walker's lesson on egghead :) At any rate, his course link ^^^ is worth the time if you want to dig deeper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was passing the root viewController, not the view, to the method. Instead, it should be this:

```
MDCSnackbarManager.setPresentationHostView(rootVC().view); //duh
const rootVC = function(){
    let appWindow = UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow;
    return appWindow.rootViewController;
}
```